# Return answer without finishing the function with cherrypy

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have simple server on `cherrypy`

```
@cherrypy.expose
class SideManager(object):

    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
    @cherrypy.expose
    def ROUTE_ONE(self, **kwargs):      
        input_json = cherrypy.request.json      
        some_result = some_func(input_json)
        return some_result

    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
    @cherrypy.expose
    def ROUTE_TWO(self, **kwargs):  
        input_json = cherrypy.request.json
        other_result = other_func(input_json)
        with open('some/file', 'w') as out:
            out.write(other_result)
```

I want to send request to both routes with the same input data. Can I avoid sending the same data to the server twice?

The problem is the functions `other_func` can take a while so I don't want client to wait this time without answer. Can I do this somehow?

```
def ROUTE_THREE(self, **kwargs):

    input_json = cherrypy.request.json
    some_result = some_func(input_json)
    #return some_result to client
    other_result = other_func(input_json)
    with open('some/file', 'w') as out:
        out.write(other_result)
```

Comment: What do you expect as the result? Both routes return a response. Which response would the caller receive?

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned, I want the caller to receive the first one (`some_result`) and don't wait for another

Comment: In that case, you don't want ROUTE_TWO exposed to the outside at all. You should probably save the request somewhere (in memory, in a data base, whatever) and have a separate thread which will process it later (i.e. call `other_func(input_json)`), after the response is sent.

Comment: Got it, thank you for you help!